# Copy the second line of a csv in one directory to a csv in another directory

Tags: bash, shell

File.csv is in directory: /a/b/c/File.csv

I want to copy the second line of File.csv in output.csv which has to be created in  directory /a

So the final output is:

/a/output.csv

I tried to run in directory /a the command:

sed -n '2p' /a/b/c/File.csv>output.csv

But it didn't work.

I also tried to run in directory /a/b/c the command:
sed -n '2p' File.csv>/a/output.csv

But it dind't work

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure your file does not have a carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

The line number goes outside of the '' as in:

sed -n 2'p' sourcefile.csv > destfile.csv

Here, -n suppresses output of the unspecified line, and 'p' is the actual command to sed for what to do with line 2.  By the way, you can separate the ">" redirection from the input and output file names, to make things a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your help!,  the command is working! it seems that the file genereted was hidden so I just need to go to the folder and press ctrl+H

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
head -2 /a/b/c/File.csv | tail -1 > /a/output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!