# How to run a command for folders that start with the word SAM and are inside another folder?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to run a command for all the folders that start with the word SAM which are inside another folder called date (the date changes)and folder date is inside another folder called subject_01 (subject changes) and the folder subject_01 is inside the main folder called root.

Structure:

```
root/subject/date/SAM_folders
```

This is the command I want to run and need to be executed from the folder date:

```
dtiConvPrep.sh folder_name
```

Example:

```
dtiConvPrep.sh SAM_03_14_25
```

I created a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(/root/*/*) #this vector contains all the folders (subject/date)
len=${#array[@]}

for (( q=0; q<$len; q++ ));    
do

cd ${array[$q]} #To execute the command from the folder date for each subject
    sleep 1

dtiConvPrep.sh SAM*   

done
```

But it only runs for 1 SAM folder in each folder called date for all the subjects.

Any idea how can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: And see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957519/how-can-i-print-the-name-of-the-antepenultimate-folder-of-a-directory-bash#comment109587312_61957519) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779325/copy-the-second-line-of-a-csv-in-one-directory-to-a-csv-in-another-directory#comment109583276_61779325)

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in /root/*/*/SAM_*; do
    (
        cd "$(dirname "$dir")"
        dtiConvPrep.sh "$(basename "$dir")"
    )
done
```

A `for ((i = 0; i < len; ++i))` style loop is a very C-/Java-like thing to do. In Bash it's more idiomatic to iterate over arrays directly. Or in this case, iterate over the glob directly.

I put parentheses around the loop body so the `cd`s run in a subshell and are only temporary. It's not necessary here since you're `cd`ing to absolute paths, but it's a good habit to get into. I like to avoid `cd`ing in the middle of scripts as it changes global state in an easy to mess up way.

You may find all the double quotes a bit of an eyesore but it's a good habit to always quote variable expansions and `$(...)` expansions in case they contain whitespace or other special characters. In this script we need nested quotes to be 100% safe.